# Empty cookieJar Instagram Login Python

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram, keyerror

I'm trying to login to Instagram with requests, but unfortunately I can't get 'csrftoken', 'sessionId' or 'ds_user_id'. When I run following code I get this KeyError:

```
"name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None".
```

Code:

```
import requests
import json
import time

# Variables
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
REFERER_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1'
USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWD = 'pasword'
IGQ = r"https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=58712303d941c6855d4e888c5f0cd22f&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%2225025320%22%2C%22first%22%3A24%7D"

session = requests.Session()
req = session.get(LOGIN_URL)
session.headers = {'user-agent': USER_AGENT}
session.headers.update({'Referer': REFERER_URL})
session.headers = {'user-agent': USER_AGENT}
session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
session.headers.update({'sessionid': req.cookies['sessionid']})
login_data = {'username': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWD}
login = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
```

After taking a closer look at the cookies (req.cookies) it turns out that the cookieJar is empty:

```
(<RequestsCookieJar[]>)
```

The response headers (req.headers) are:

```
{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Allow': 'POST',
'Cache-Control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT',
'Vary': 'Cookie, Accept-Language', 'Content-Language': 'en', 'Date':
'Tue, 10 Jul 2018 13:25:12 GMT', 'Strict-Transport-Security':
'max-age=86400', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '0'}
```

I'm totally stuck here and was searching the web a while now and couldn't find a solution that works for me, so it would be great if somebody could help me with that!